# how to validate input for phone number with start of +966 only?

Tags: html

I'm trying to creating validation for input so the user can only input number start with +966 then 9 numbers like +966123456789

this is what i'm using but it doesn't do what i need

```
<input name="mobile" type="tel" pattern="^\d{13}$" required>
```

it gives 13 numbers the plus and 12 numbers but i need it to start with +966 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="mobile" type="tel" pattern="^\+966\d{1,9}$" title="validation message here" required>
```

Comment: Note that this does not prevent the form from being submitted in, e.g. Safari, and a couple browsers don't support it.

Comment: @Tomm Can you help me changing the "please match the requested format" message?

Comment: In the example above there is
   ` title="validation message here"`

Comment: The title didn't work for me but I've found this oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('New Message')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"

Comment: @Tomm Thanks :)

Comment: @Tomm Actually I found that the numbers not always 9 numbers so how can I make it only start with +966 then any numbers

Comment: @Hossam Ahmed see updated pattern, now it requires 1 to 9 numbers (besides +966).
Instead of "\d{1,9}", you can use "\d+" which means "minimum one number"